# ImageMagick problem with identify of DNG Image without extension

Tags: imagemagick

I'm trying to get format, filesize, width and height from an DNG Image. With a .DNG extension `identify L1004220.dng` returns the correct data: `L1004220.DNG DNG 5216x3472 5216x3472+0+0 16-bit sRGB 17.4867MiB 0.000u 0:00.003`.

The problem now is, I've made a md5 hash from the filename and stored it somewhere else, lets call the file `17a14024496c3bea3b81362510962785`. Now if I run the same command with the md5 filename it will give me another result: `17a14024496c3bea3b81362510962785 TIFF 320x216 320x216+0+0 8-bit sRGB 17.4867MiB 0.010u 0:00.008`

It somehow identified it as a TIFF instead of a DNG image.

But when I give `17a14024496c3bea3b81362510962785` a .dng extension, it again works.

I only have this problem with DNG images. Other formats work as expected.

I run it on Linux. I installed the `libraw-dev` package which ImageMagick uses as a delegate for DNG Images. I use a self compiled ImageMagick 7.

For testing I used a sample image (Original DNG (18MB)) from here https://www.kenrockwell.com/leica/m9/sample-photos-3.htm

Anyone encountered this problem before? Am I using the wrong package as delegate?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by adding `dng:` before the filename like:

`identify dng:17a14024496c3bea3b81362510962785`

result:

`dng:17a14024496c3bea3b81362510962785=>17a14024496c3bea3b81362510962785 DNG 5216x3472 5216x3472+0+0 16-bit sRGB 17.4867MiB 0.010u 0:00.003`